# OpenGL in Fedora as a VMWare guest under Windows 7

Tags: linux, fedora, graphics, vmware, opengl

I installed Fedora 14 (64-bit) on a Windows 7 64 bits system, as a guest in VMWare. I can't use OpenGL support, Compiz and other openGL programs do not work. I searched on Google; I found solutions if both the guest and the host run Linux or if both the guest and the host run Windows.

How can I use OpenGL with a Windows host and Linux guest in VMWare?

Answer (score 1):

Reat That Fantastic Manual.

From [VMware Workstation User's Manual for VMware Workstation 7.1](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/ws71_manual.pdf), pages 172 and 173:

> **Accelerated 3-D Restrictions**
>
> Support for applications that use
>   DirectX 9 accelerated graphics applies
>   only to  Windows XP guests, on hosts
>   running Windows XP, Windows Vista,
>   Windows 7, or  Linux. This feature
>   currently has the following
>   restrictions:
>
> - Workstation now offers support for    DirectX games and applications with
>     DirectX versions 9 and lower.
> - Support for 3‐D applications is not optimized for performance.
> - *OpenGL applications run in software    emulation mode.*
> - You cannot use the record/replay.

If the support for OpenGL is missing
for Linux guests in Workstation 7.1 I
don't think it's present in any
previous version. Documentation for
VMware Server does not even mention
OpenGL.

[Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)